# Q: Issue with installing scipy (windows)

Tags: python, scipy, python-import

I tried to initially install scipy by running `pip install scipy` and got `error: no lapack/blas resources found`and so I downloaded anaconda for python 2.7. Once I installed anaconda, I once again ran `pip install scipy` and the issue had resolved, and it said `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy in c:\users\owner\anaconda2\lib\site-packages`, however when I tried to import scipy in the python console, I got the error `No module named scipy`. I am on windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda python comes with its own package manager. The command is:

```
conda install scipy
```

In case you want to install it in a specific environment go for:

```
conda install -n myEnv scipy
```

Please check http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: I ran `conda install scipy` successfully and I'm still getting the error `No module named scipy` when I try to import scipy

Answer (score 0):

You should check your system path. 
Checking path `c:\users\owner\anaconda2\lib\site-packages` if it is in your sys path by doing:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

if not, you should add this path into your sys path, link below may help you achieve that.

https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10